# Laravel 8: Custom Middleware Does Not Seem To Be Working

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I'm using Laravel 8 for my project and in this project and I have created a custom Middleware called `Admin` that goes like this:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

And I tried applying it like this:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('admin/users', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUserController::class);
});
```

And on `Kernel.php`:

```php
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
```

So I called the `isAdmin()` at User Model which simply checks if the role of the user is correct or not:

```php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

public function isAdmin()
{
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
        if ($role->name == 'Manual User') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Currently, I have these two roles:

[image]

And the user, that I want to log in, is set to **6** and has the role id of **1** which `Manual User`:

[image]

But now the problem is, when I go to `/admin/users` uri, it does not redirect me to `('/')` uri and shows me `/admin/users` page!

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

Note that the relationship between `roles` and `users` which is Many To Many works fine and there is no need to mention them.

Comment: Start with a sanity-check. Put a `dd('test')` as the first line in the handle method, to see if it's getting called in the first place.

Comment: @kmuenkel I put that but nothing appears on screen when I goto `/` uri and `/admin/users` uri. Why is that ?

Comment: Not sure. In `App\Http\Kernel`, your middleware is referenced in the `$routeMiddleware` array, yes?

Comment: Let's do another check. This will verify that the Route definition is what you think it is. Sometimes dynamic-routes will step on your toes a bit, if they're defined in the wrong order, mistaking a path node for a parameter and sending to the wrong Controller. In AdminUserController, make sure the method you're experimenting on it's type-hinting in a `$request` object and add this: `$route = $request->route(); dd(['path' => '('.$request->method().')'.urldecode($route->uri()), 'name' => $route->getName()]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this locally with a very similar setup and had no problem. I took the liberty of changing/simplifying some things.

These are the steps I took.

#### 1. Middleware

**1.1. Create `Admin` middleware.**

Done by running the `php artisan make:middleware Admin` command.

**1.2. Fill out the middleware.**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Passes if authenticated user is an admin.
     *
     * @see App\Models\User::isAdmin()
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Here is my first change: I don't do the `Auth::check()`. There's another middleware for that.

#### 1.3 Add new entry to `$middlewareGroups` in `App\Http\Kernel.php`.

```php
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [...],

        'api' => [...],

        // check if user is authenticated, then check if it's an admin
        'admin' => [
            'auth',
            \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        ...
    ];
```

#### 2. Route

Add a route that uses the middleware created above.

```php
Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('test', function () { return "User is authenticated and is an admin."; });
});
```

Also, optionally you could simplify your `isAdmin()` method.

```php
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->roles->contains('name', 'Manual User');
}
```

---

This, for me, had the desired results. Are you sure you edited your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file correctly?